# Special symbols in search results

Tags: php, search, magento

For the product's `name` attribute I've set `Allow HTML Tags on Frontend` to yes and special symbols are displayed correctly in product listing.

However in search results (which are using the same template `catalog\product\list.phtml` names are escaped. As far as I was able to debug `is_html_allowed_on_front` attribute property is not fetched and equals to `null`. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: @Pekka with helper's `escapeHtml` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I replaced `$_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name')` with `$_product->getName()`

If anyone got a better solution please share